# Long list of domains in iOS Entitlement file in iOS 9.0-9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, ios9, ios-universal-links

We have a need to support 100+ domains in our entitlements file for Universal Links.

```
Example:
    applinks:test.myapp.com
    applinks:blah.myapp.com
    applinks:foo.bar.com
    etc...
```

I know that *.myapp.com will be supported in iOS 9.3, but is there a way to do this elegantly for customers using iOS 9.0 to 9.2 without having to manually add 100+ entries to the entitlements file?  Is there a way to do this without having to rebuild and re-release our app every time we need to add a domain to the list?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an option of using the format `myapp.com/[blank]` rather than `[blank].myapp.com`?

Comment: We also support putting the prefix in a query string parameter but we have to support both.

Comment: Query string parameters are ignored for Universal Links entitlements ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) — though of course you can parse them out for routing after the app is opens).

Answer (score 1):

The new wildcard support in iOS 9.3 is designed for exactly the situation you're describing, so there isn't really a solid alternative in earlier OS versions.

If you don't want to worry about continually updating the list of subdomain `applinks` entries (or even if you do, but need to wait for App Store review), the best workaround is probably hosting fallback pages on each subdomain with a call-to-action the user can use to continue into the app. That would work as follows:

1. Assume that you have `applinks:mydomain.com` configured.
2. User opens a link to `new.mydomain.com/exciting-page` (which is NOT covered by the entitlement above).
3. User sees a custom interstitial, functionally similar to [something like this](https://branch.io/features/#deepviews). On this interstitial is a link pointing to `mydomain.com/new/exciting-page`
4. User opens the link and the app launches.

The only thing I am not sure about is whether `mydomain.com` and `new.mydomain.com` count as 'different domains' for the purpose of Universal Links, since Universal Linking functionality is disabled in Safari for links within the same domain ([source](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links)). If this turns out not to work, you could easily use something like `applinks:mydomain.io` and a link to `mydomain.io/new/exciting-page` in step 3 instead.